# I can't click on the buttons, selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to click on all the buttons to reveal all the content, first I collect all the buttons, then I click on them through the cycle.

But I get an error

> Message: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (1223, 15). Other element would receive the click: ...
> (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time

URL = 'https://masterwatt.ru/catalog/kotly-gazovye-nastennye/' 

option = Options()
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1 
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),chrome_options=option)

def parser_get_url_content():
    driver.get(URL)
    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds

        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height

    time.sleep(4)
    btn_plus = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('b-count__btn--plus')

    for btn in btn_plus:
        time.sleep(2)
        btn.click()
    


def get_url_content():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser_get_url_content()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    
btn.Send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```